# Generating Function for a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, generating-functions

The problem I am trying to solve is mentioned as such:

> Let a random variable $ξ$ take values in $Z_+$ and $Eξ < ∞$.
> (a) Prove that $ϕ_ξ$ is monotone, bounded and continuous on $[0, 1]$.
> (b) Let $ξ_n$ take values in $Z_+$ and $ξ_n
> \overset{d}{\to}  ξ$. Prove that the convergence ${ϕ_ξ}_n\xrightarrow{} ϕ_ξ$ is
> uniform on $[0, 1]$.

Here $ϕ_ξ$ is generating function for the random variable $ξ$ So from the definition of generating function $ϕ_ξ(Z)$ will be $E Z^ξ$. But I am not sure how to prove the above statements. While searching more on this I found about continuity theorem but I did not find how it is proved. Any lead or help is very much appreciated.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What is $Z_+$? The positive integers?

Comment: @Raskolnikov Yes

Comment: What have you tried? Can show that $\phi_\zeta$ exists on $[0, 1]$, for instance? What do you know about power series?

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson $ϕ_ξ(Z) =E Z^ξ = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^kp(ξ=k)$ now if ξ has poission distribution then we can rewrite the above equation as $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k \frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}$ (using taylor series we get )$=e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda{q}} = e^{\lambda{(q-1)}}$

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson then I believe we can draw the graph for the same in the given interval to see its behaviour